# Refreshing select2 drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm trying to dynamically change the option of a select2 dropdown.

I've searched the forum and have managed to change the selected option, but it is only visible when clicking on the dropdown and seeing the entire list. Apologies in advance for not being the best coder.

```
function changeSelectOption(designSelVal) //designSelVal = 9

{   
    var opts = document.getElementById("design").options;
    for (var opt, i = 0; opt = opts[i]; i++) 
    {
    if (opt.value == design) 
        {
            document.getElementById("design").selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

/* this shows as having correctly changed from value 2 to 9 */

```
<option value="2" >Text Only</option>
<option value="4" >Heart Arrow</option>
<option value="9" selected>Heart</option>
```

The visible option remains 'Text Only' and not 'Heart', it's as if the select box needs refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the if condition :

it should be

```
if (opt.value == designSelVal)
```

```js
function changeSelectOption(designSelVal) //designSelVal = 9

    {
     
      var opts = document.getElementById("design").options;
      
      for (var opt, i = 0; opt = opts[i]; i++) {
        
        if (opt.value == designSelVal) {
          document.getElementById("design").selectedIndex = i;

          break;
        } 
      }
    }

    changeSelectOption(9);
```

```html
    <select id="design">
      <option value="2" selected>Text Only</option>
      <option value="4">Heart Arrow</option>
      <option value="9" >Heart</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: The use of an 'if' statement isn't an issue, the function is called and passed with a 9. The associated option is then correctly assigned. The issue is with it being a select2 I think the object needs refreshing etc as the newly selected option isn't viewable unless you click to see the entire dropdown list, it's not becoming the single viewable value from a visual perspective.